# Git diff from script

Tags: git, git-diff

I am trying to write a script which takes a regular expression for commit log messages and then displays the git diff across all the commits. I have the following in my script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
ARGV=("$@")
dir=$(pwd)
commits=($(git --work-tree ${dir} log --grep ${ARGV[0]} | grep -o 'commit .*$' | cut -f2 -d' '))
echo $(git --work-tree ${dir} log --grep ${ARGV[0]})
for i in ${commits[@]}
do
    echo "command: git diff ${i}"
    echo $(git diff ${i})
 done
```

When I run `/path/to/script.sh <some-regex>` I get the following output:

> command: git diff 806e5e76c0b20eabda3a14b1442168149ad30155
>
> fatal: ambiguous argument '806e5e76c0b20eabda3a14b1442168149ad30155': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git  [...] -- [...]'

However when I run the actual command that is output everything works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: In which shell do you execute this script? It doesn't even run on bash!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a script which takes a regular expression for commit log messages then
>   displays the git diff across all the commits

Doesn’t this do that?

```
git log --patch --grep=<pattern>
```

[explainshell.com - git log --patch --grep](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+log+--patch+--grep)